# An error occurred in the Microsoft . NET Framework while trying to load assembly

Tags: sql-server, view, .net-assembly

I am trying to create a view which should select data from snapshot database table on SQL Server 2017.
However I become the following error:

> An error occurred in the Microsoft . NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65536. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted.

The problem is with one assembly, but in case of other views everything works fine. Any suggestions what needs to be done?

Comment: Debug that assembly? This refers to a SQLCLR assembly I presume?

Comment: please provide your piece of code that you are getting the related error